# macro error when copying print area and pasting to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have created the code below which works up to a point then I get a run-time error 1004.  Could anyone help?  The error dialog box says that "PasteSpecial method of Range Class failed" and the first .PasteSpecial line is highlighted.

```
Sub CopyPO()
'
' CopyPO Macro
'

'
   Dim rngPrintArea As Range
   Set rngPrintArea = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea)
With Sheets("Inventory").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
End With
End Sub
```

To clarify, I am trying to copy the print area of the active sheet and paste it in the next available cell on the inventory sheet. This code works if the range is a specific range of cells (i.e. A1:P55) but I want to copy and paste the print area if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you figured out yourself, you need to copy the range and then use `PasteSpecial`. So add `rngPrintArea.Copy` before your with-block.

Later, if you want to add the recently pasted cells to the print area in the `"Inventory"` worksheet then you need this:

```
Sub CopyPO()

   Dim rngPrintArea As Range
   Dim newRange As Range

   Set rngPrintArea = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea)
   rngPrintArea.Copy

   With Sheets("Inventory").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
   End With

  Set newRange = Sheets("Inventory").Range(ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea)

  'If you want print area to be only the recent pasted range change the following line _
  'to commented line below;

  Set newRange = newRange.Resize(newRange.Rows.Count + _
                 rngPrintArea.Rows.Count, newRange.Columns.Count)

  'Set newRange = Sheets("Inventory").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0). _
   'Resize(rngPrintArea.Rows.Count,rngPrintArea.Columns.Count)

  Sheets("Inventory").PageSetup.PrintArea = newRange.Address

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Like This

```
Sub CopyPO()

' CopyPO Macro

   Dim rngPrintArea As Range
   Set rngPrintArea = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea)
   rngPrintArea.Copy
   With Sheets("Inventory").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
   End With
End Sub
```

However - I could do with adding the copied range to the print area in the Inventory...  Do you know what I'd have to add to make that work?  I have played around with it myself but haven't sussed that yet...

Comment: Basically forgot to copy the range. That's your answer. right?

Comment: Correct.  If you can help in adding it too the print area though that would be awesome.

Comment: I seriously have a hard time trying to figure out what do you mean by your comment and the last paragraph in your answer. I don't think you want something hard. Only if you can express yourself, you'd get help.

Comment: @Masoud - all I'm saying is that I want to add the copied cells to the print area once pasted.  As you say not too hard, I think I have solved it by adding ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = rngPrintArea before the End With.  Doesn't work perfectly though.

Comment: add them to the print area for `Inventory` sheet? if Yes, I am posting an answer.

Comment: Yes, the Inventory sheet

Answer (score -1):

There's no code indicating something is being copied.  If you add a line to copy, it looks like that'll work.

Comment: !  I had missed that off!  Amazing what you can overlook :)